# Lookup in VBA but copy all cell contents including comments

Tags: excel, vba

Hi alI am trying to copy data from a series of workbooks into a master file. The master file contains the spreadsheet names, and sheet names to loop through as strings and I have that process working fine. But now I need to match the names in column A and row 1 with the data in each worksheet and copy the cell including any comments. I had the vlookup working but it does not copy the comments. So I have tried to do a couple of match statements to find the cell column and row numbers but cannot seem to get it to work. Any ideas??

```
Sub GroupTwo()
Dim path As String
Dim i As Integer
Dim Dsheet As String
Dim wb As Workbook
Dim upi
Dim cmt As Comment
Dim iRow As Integer
Dim col As Integer
Dim lookrange As Range
Dim G2 As Worksheet
Dim colRange As Variant
Dim rowRange As Range
Dim rowCell As Variant
Dim colCell As Variant

Set lookrange = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Lookups").Range(ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Lookups").Cells(3, 1), ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Lookups").Cells(11, 2))
Set G2 = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Group_two")

Application.DisplayAlerts = False
upi = 2
coln = 2
For i = 60 To 61
    path = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet7").Cells(1, i).Value
    Dsheet = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet7").Cells(2, i).Value
    Set wb = Workbooks.Open(path)
    Set colRange = wb.Sheets(Dsheet).Range(wb.Sheets(Dsheet).Cells(4, 2), wb.Sheets(Dsheet).Cells(4, 56))
    Set rowRange = wb.Sheets(Dsheet).Range(wb.Sheets(Dsheet).Cells(7, 1), wb.Sheets(Dsheet).Cells(27, 1))
    For c = 2 To 57
        For r = 8 To 73
            Set rowCell = Application.Match(G2.Cells(r, 1), rowRange, 0)
            Set colCell = Application.Match(G2.Cells(4, c), colRange, 0)
            wb.Sheets(Dsheet).Range(rowCell, colCell).Copy
            G2.Cells(r, c).PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteComments, Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks:=False, Transpose:=False


        Next r
    Next c
    do some stuff with the comment
    wb.Close SaveChanges:=False
Next i
```

Comment: @ARich thanks for the suggestion that is the way I used to have it and I have changed it back to that approach. The problem I'm getting is earl;ier on with an error 13 type mismatch on the first set rowCell = application.match   not sure what to do here

Answer (score 0):

Have you considered copying everything over at the same time?

So instead of this:

```
G2.Cells(r, c).Value = wb.Sheets(Dsheet).Range(rowCell, ColCell, colRange, 0)).copy
```

Maybe you could do this:

```
wb.Sheets(Dsheet).Range(rowCell, ColCell, colRange, 0)).copy
G2.Cells(r, c).PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteComments, Operation:=xlNone, _
    SkipBlanks:=False, Transpose:=False
```

[See this link](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff839476.aspx) for more information on the `PasteSpecial` method.
[See this link](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff837425.aspx) for more information on the different paste types.